# Should I rotate the standing foot to throw a roundhouse kick?

Tags: karate, kicking, muay-thai, mixed-martial-arts

I stand southpaw, with my less flexible right foot in front. To throw a roundhouse kick, my Kyokushin training makes it feel natural for me to plant my left foot solid on the ground to kick with the right. Maybe occasionally I will slightly rotate the standing (non-kicking) foot, if I am going for a Thai style roundhouse. Is it OK to plant the standing foot, or should I rotate the standing foot to throw a roundhouse kick?

Comment: What is your goal and distance? In Kyokushin, you typically have a rather short distance and one of your main goals is not telegraphing too early what you are going for (hence the knee movement of your kicking leg being paramount). In kickboxing, you have more distance and work with lead-ins. In muay thai, it depends on whether your talking coming from clinch or distance. And then there's speed and impact...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the more power you want to put in a roundhouse kick, and the more you want it to penetrate the target, the more you should pivot that supporting foot (and possibly start by stepping to the side of the kick). The reason why is fairly obvious in that you need to be able to deliver the full power of the kick close to the center of your body and, without pivoting the support leg, that means you're essentially either not using your hips as much (a common situation for snap roundhouses in Tae Kwan Do, especially to the head) or your supporting leg is essentially being forced to rotate heavily in the other direction (since the rest of your body is rotating).

Comment: weird thing is that my left foot is more flexible than the right and when I try to perform a roundhouse with my left I do it almost perfectly with good form, except with less power than my right. So with my left, my supporting foot rotate almost a 180 degree, while my hips rotates. While with my not so flexible right leg, my supporting left foot rotates barely maybe about 45 or 60 degrees from the normal position and I am able to performe (IMO) a good roundhouse with good power and hip movement. So in conclusion, I honestly don't know......

Comment: if the rotation of the supporting foot neccesary. Cuz I experience two different conflicting things, with my left and right. Also to note, when throwing a low roundhose my supporting leg actually rotates a good deal. It's when doing a high roundhouse is where I get into trouble.

Comment: @EPICTubeHD: I'll be honest. I don't know if I have enough information to diagnose the problem even if I had the expertise (I did Tae Kwan Do for a while, but most of my experience is in Capoeira, which operates differently). Can you post video of you doing the kick on each side?

Comment: IME, the action of the supporting leg is so important in executing a kick it's not unusual for the kick to be better when standing on the "strong" foot.  You might think the right kick is more powerful - but how are you measuring it?  Noise on the bag?  Just "feeling" better?